# Issue with a position relative on Chrome and Android native browser

Tags: jquery, css, position

First post here, after a long time using your advices ! 

So, here is my problem : I try to center an element horizontally. I've defined 'top:50%' in CSS and ask jQuery to find 'margin-top:-XXpx'. 

It works on load, but when I refresh the page with Chrome or Android native browser, the element moves below. 

This doesn't happen with Firefox (i haven't tried with other browsers). 

you can see it here : http://www.porteguillau.me/2/

Does someone have any idea ?

Comment: Relative code would immensely help. I doubt you need jquery to solve this issue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use absolute positioning in stead of relative.

Also, Are you trying to centre the div vertically? If you know the height (which you should if the icons are fixed sizes), set the top margin to negative half the height of the div (In your example -150px or so).

Comment: BTW you can do all of what I just said with just CSS. As a general rule, avoid using jquery for layout unless you have to.

Comment: Thanks, it's safer like this, but i'd like my icons to have a size  equal to x% of the body. The parent element of the icons is set here to center them horizontally. But i suppose that it is not possible to define the size of an element based on his "grand"-parent (body->element->icons)